# How can i sign out from twitter using ios5?

Tags: iphone, twitter, logout, ios5

I have used Twitter framework for login and tweet from iphone app .Now i want logout when one switch is set off so how i can do this?
Can any one help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Twitter.framework` is a system wide implementation of Twitter and you can't log an user out since the user is logged in to twitter with just you app but the hole system.